# DB2 server 7.3 needs a compatible db2 library for eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, db2, ibm-midrange

[image: Here is the error I get] I get this error. I have DB2 for i Series 7.3s, I know it is a old version, but I can't change it. I just want to find the Db2 library compatible with Db2 7.3 for my eclipse maven project. Please help. If you can locate me the compatible library. I am looking for the correct Db2 library for Db2 version 7.3

Comment: Look in the documentation.  The JDBC driver is often installed with the rest so you just need the name so you can locate it.

Comment: Does your Db2-server run on i-series (as400) ?  Please update your question to clarify.  If you need a jdbc driver to communicate with as400 Db2, then you can either use an IBM-supplied jdbc driver (may need licensing), or you can use the jt400 driver (assuming your Db2 server runs on i-series).

Comment: I get the driver not supported exception for my db2 driver as an error in the server log. I want to stop getting that error in the server log.

Comment: What DB2 driver version do you use ? Could you show the pom.xml dependency ?

Comment: Even the latest DB2 driver for i version 11 does not support your method : `// JDBC 2.0
    /**
    Returns the type map.
    <p>This driver does not support the type map.
    **/
     abstract public Map getTypeMap ()
    throws SQLException;`

Answer (score 0):

Look like this was due to incompatibility between the connection created by your driver and ConnectionPool you are using.
At snaq.db.CacheConnection.getTypeMap()

```
 public Map getTypeMap() throws SQLException
    {
        return con.getTypeMap();
    }
```

May be while getting the TypeMap Object from the connection object, it's throwing the exception.

Comment: where do I have to put this code? I do not understand

Comment: No, just look alternate way for ConnectionPool statergy.